# android related project

Tags: android

I'm looking for an android related project. I'm an upcoming graduating student and is required to finish a project. The project should be done within 5 months so the project should be feasible. Any of you guys have any ideas? I tried proposing an android lighting system but got denied so I'm looking for other ideas.

Comment: Is that a programming question ? Might be better suited the Android Enthusiasts site...

Comment: Yeah, it is a programming question. I'm visiting the sites you said. I just tried here for luck. Thanks

Comment: its not a programming question, and you just can't post it here

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.seminarprojects.com/Thread-android-project-ideas-for-students) you can find better android project definitions .

Comment: thanks. I will definitely check the site. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try making a project which integrates into apps or accounts and changes the password accordingly to the current time...or maybe a diary (with this function possible)....or maybe a locked file storage (with this function again)....and also create a generator for it...should be simple...just suggesting as you said

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Appreciate it.  What I had mind is an Android device controlling something. You know, like an RC car or a RC helicopter. I tried proposing the android controlled RC car it was denied because it served no purpose. Tried with the RC copter, I got quoted feasible but it lacks other features.

Comment: the locked storage is already made

Comment: @Alexander but not with a timely changing password